# how to get the records order by week no from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am creating a web app in php and i am trying to get the records from the database according to the group of the given date

for example, I'll get the date like (2014-10) now i have to get all the records having the same week no like 10 result on 1st week(1-7 date)
20 result in the 2nd week

I have tried the following queries and also much mode th e others but no effect

```
select sum(orders) where week('2014-10')='week('".$input_date."')';
```

Comment: Can you share the table's structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use like here no need of making things complex. Assuming you do not have the yyyy-mm-dd format. Example shows that you have format like yyyy-week.
Your input date variable should be like $input_date = '-10'.

For example:

```
select sum(orders) where week like "%-10";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT WEEK(order_date), sum(orders)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY WEEK(order_date)
//without this HAVING, you see the sums of all available weeks
HAVING WEEK(order_date)=week('".$input_date."')
```